# Static color type initializer extension method

Tags: c#, colors, static, extension-methods

I want to create a extension method for `System.Windows.Media.Color`.

The method should create a `Color` instance from HSV values without me having to create a new instace manually first. But currently my snippet **totally overrides** the `Color` class.

If I add it as a normal ExtensionMethod, I can use it like this:

```
var color = new Color().FromHSV(1, 1, 250);
```

But I want to use it this way:

```
var color = Color.FromHSV(1, 1, 250);
```

This is what I got so far (but overrides the complete existing `Color` class):

```
namespace System.Windows.Media
{
    public class Color
    {
        public static Color FromHSV(double hue, double saturation, double value)
        {
            int hi = (byte)(Math.Floor(hue / 60)) % 6;
            double f = hue / 60 - Math.Floor(hue / 60);

            value = value * 255;
            byte v = (byte)value;
            byte p = (byte)(value * (1 - saturation));
            byte q = (byte)(value * (1 - f * saturation));
            byte t = (byte)(value * (1 - (1 - f) * saturation));

            if (hi == 0)
                return Color.FromArgb(255, v, t, p);
            else if (hi == 1)
                return Color.FromArgb(255, q, v, p);
            else if (hi == 2)
                return Color.FromArgb(255, p, v, t);
            else if (hi == 3)
                return Color.FromArgb(255, p, q, v);
            else if (hi == 4)
                return Color.FromArgb(255, t, p, v);
            else
                return Color.FromArgb(255, v, p, q);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what some of the other posters have said, you cannot do this exactly like you want. Why not just approach the problem from a different angle?

```
var colour = HSV.CreateColor(1, 1, 250);
```

Declared as:

```
public static class HSV
{
    public static Color CreateColor(double hue, double saturation, double value)
    {
        Color color = new Color();
        // Do HSV things..
        return color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create extension methods that act like static methods. Extension methods are only allowed to be called on instances.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. There are a few other options though;

- Create a wrapper, something like `ColorHelper`, which contains all extensions. Usage would be something like `ColorHelper.FromHSV()`.
- Use different namespaces.

Example of the second point:

```
using WMC = System.Windows.Media.Color;
using MyColorNamespace;

public class Program
{
    public void Foo()
    {
         var bar = WMC.ColorMethod();
         var bar2 = MyColorNamespace.FromHSV(0,0,0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not feel like an extension method..

Because an extension method must be a static method in static class and the first param must be the object to extend.

Like this :

```
 namespace ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static class MyExtensions
        {
            public static int WordCount(this String str)
            {
                return str.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?' }, 
                                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
            }
        }   
    }
```